# Combine row values based on multiple ID in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate

I have dataframe *df* of which a sample is shown below. I need to combine the rows by *study_id*, *lab_study_dt*, and *lab_study_time*, and have NA and non-NA values across labs and detection limits on the same row grouped by those three key variables.

I've tried group by and summarise_all to do this but didn't get the outcome I'm looking for.

```
df %>%
    group_by(study_id,lab_study_dt,lab_study_time) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(toString(na.omit(.))))
```

| study_id | lab_study_dt | lab_study_time | lab_polys | lab_lymphs | lab_mono | lab_eos | lab_basos | lab_bands | lab_wbc_count | lab_rbc_count | protein_limit_of_detection | lab_protein | gluc_limit_of_detection | lab_glucose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | 8/13/2011 | 0:12 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 1 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Jane | 8/13/2011 | 0:12 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Jane | 3/4/2013 | 15:27 | NA | 60 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Jane | 3/4/2013 | 15:27 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 10000 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Jane | 3/4/2013 | 15:27 | 8 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Jane | 3/4/2013 | 15:27 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 1 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Jane | 3/4/2013 | 15:27 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 149 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Jane | 3/4/2013 | 15:27 | NA | NA | 31 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 1 | 56 | NA | NA |
| George | 4/20/2021 | 21:18 | NA | 60 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| George | 4/20/2021 | 21:18 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 10000 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| George | 4/23/2021 | 15:27 | 8 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 2 | 3 |
| George | 4/23/2021 | 12:27 | NA | 65 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 1 | >10 | NA | NA |
| George | 4/23/2021 | 12:27 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 1 | 149 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| George | 4/23/2021 | 12:27 | NA | NA | 31 | NA | NA | NA | NA | 56 | NA | NA | NA | NA |

The end dataframe would have one row per unique study_id, study date, and study time together, with all associated values along that row. So for example, entry Jane - 3/4/2013 - 15:27 would look like below:

| study_id | lab_study_dt | lab_study_time | lab_polys | lab_lymphs | lab_mono | lab_eos | lab_basos | lab_bands | lab_wbc_count | lab_rbc_count | protein_limit_of_detection | lab_protein | gluc_limit_of_detection | lab_glucose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | 3/4/2013 | 15:27 | 8 | 60 | 31 | NA | NA | 1 | 149 | 1000 | 1 | 56 | NA | NA |

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there only one non-NA value per column per group you care about? If so, you  might group, then use `tidyr::fill` and then `dplyr::distinct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could group by the `id/dt/time`, then use `tidyr::fill` on all columns (ie `everything()`) to take any non-NA values and copy them first down through any NAs and then up though any NAs ("downup", my arbitrary choice). Finally, we can keep just the first slice within each group and then remove the grouping.

```
library(tidyverse)    
df %>%
  group_by(study_id,lab_study_dt,lab_study_time) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Is this the output you'd expect?

```
# A tibble: 5 × 15
  study_id lab_study_dt lab_study_time lab_polys lab_lymphs lab_mono lab_eos lab_basos lab_bands lab_wbc_count lab_rbc_count protein_limit_of_detection lab_protein gluc_limit_of_detecti… lab_glucose
  <chr>    <chr>        <chr>              <int>      <int>    <int> <lgl>   <lgl>         <int>         <int>         <int>                      <int> <chr>                        <int>       <int>
1 George   4/20/2021    21:18                 NA         60       NA NA      NA               NA            NA         10000                         NA NA                              NA          NA
2 George   4/23/2021    12:27                 NA         65       31 NA      NA                1           149            56                          1 >10                             NA          NA
3 George   4/23/2021    15:27                  8         NA       NA NA      NA               NA            NA            NA                         NA NA                               2           3
4 Jane     3/4/2013     15:27                  8         60       31 NA      NA                1           149         10000                          1 56                              NA          NA
5 Jane     8/13/2011    0:12                  NA         NA       NA NA      NA               NA             1            NA                         NA NA                              NA          NA
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work! Thank you. Would you mind explaining your reasoning behind this for me?

Comment: Added some explanation, hope that helps.